# Microsoft Excel: How can I make a numbered range that adjusts when I delete cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically, I want a list of numbers with gaps, if that makes sense.

Here's ideally what it would look like (each of these items is a separate cell):

Example A:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

   (subcategory of item 3)

   (subcategory of item 4)
4. Item 4

This is what I currently have using Excel's autofill numbers:

Example B:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3
4. (subcategory of item 3)
5. (subcategory of item 4)
6. Item 4

I'd like to be able to delete the numbers 4. and 5. in example B and have the remaining numbered cells adjust themselves to look like example A, which saves me from having to go through my long spreadsheet manually adjusting the numbers. Is this possible in Excel? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an auto-adjusting list by putting the formula

```
=MAX(A$1:A1)+1
```

into cell `A2`, leaving cell `A1` blank
(or putting something non-numeric, like a column heading, there). 
Drag/fill down as required. 
This sets each cell to be
one more than the largest (maximum) value in the column above it. 
Naïvely, that means a one-up counter. 
But, if you clear some cells,

[image: sample spreadsheet with numbered list, before and after clearing]

(as I have done here with `A6` and `A7`),
the numbering jumps the gap the way you want it to,
because the largest value in the column `A1:A7` (above `A8`)
is 4 (in `A5`), so `A8` gets set to 5.